# Creating another column in pandas based on a pre-existing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a third column in my data frame where I want to be able to create a fourth column that looks almost the same, except it has no double quotes and there is a 'user/' prefix before each ID in the list. Also, sometimes it is just a single ID vs. list of IDs (as shown in example DF).

original

```
col1   col2     col3 
01      01     "ID278, ID289"

02      02     "ID275"
```

desired

```
col1   col2     col3                col4
01      01     "ID278, ID289"     user/ID278, user/ID289

02      02     "ID275"            user/ID275
```

Comment: I added a method that deals with rows that are empty, either filled with `np.nan` or empty strings `''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
   col1  col2            col3
0   1.0   1.0  "ID278, ID289"
1   2.0   2.0         "ID275"
2   2.0   1.0             NaN
```

Doing:

```
df['col4'] = (df.col3.str.strip('"')  # Remove " from both ends.
                     .str.split(', ') # Split into lists on ', '.
                     .apply(lambda x: ['user/' + i for i in x if i] # Apply this list comprehension,
                                       if isinstance(x, list)  # If it's a list.
                                       else x)
                     .str.join(', ')) # Join them back together.
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2            col3                    col4
0   1.0   1.0  "ID278, ID289"  user/ID278, user/ID289
1   2.0   2.0         "ID275"              user/ID275
2   2.0   1.0             NaN                     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .apply() function:

```
def function(x):
    if not x:
        return ""
    
    elements = x.split(", ")
    out = list()
    
    for i in elements:
        out.append(f"user/{i}")
        
    return ", ".join(out)

df["col4"] = df.col3.apply(function)
```

That returns:

```
col1  col2  col3          col4
1     1     ID278, ID289  user/ID278, user/ID289
2     2     ID275         user/ID275
3     3
```

Comment: I also forgot to mention there are some rows that are empty in col 3, would you please revise the code for this aspect?

Comment: I updated the function, it will make that the empty rows return a empty string for the new column

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that takes both the double quotes and ID lists into account:

```py
# remove the double quotes
df['col4'] = df['col3'].str.strip('"')
# split the string, add prefix user/, and then join
df['col4'] = df['col4'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(f"user/{userId}" for userId in x.split(', ')))
```

Comment: I also forgot to mention there are some rows that are empty in col 3, would you please revise the code for this aspect?